# Installing Oro on Windows with Docker fails

Tags: installation, orocommerce

I tried to install OroCommerce 5.0.0 Community Edition on my Windows machine following these documentations.

https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/setup/dev-environment/docker-and-symfony/
https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/setup/dev-environment/docker-and-symfony/windows/

Requirements etc. are fine.

but on Step 5: *symfony console oro:install -vvv --sample-data=y --application-url=https://127.0.0.1:8000 --user-name=admin --user-email=admin@example.com --user-firstname=John --user-lastname=Doe --user-password=admin --organization-name=Oro --timeout=0 --symlink --env=prod -n*

Filling the database etc works fine, but when it comes to translation the installation fails  and this error occurs:

**In Filesystem.php line 190:


FilesystemIterator::__construct(/mnt/c/DPI_Projects/OroPlattform/orocommerce-application/var/cache/dev/..Ux0): Failed to open directory: No such file or directory 


oro:translation:load [-l|--languages [LANGUAGES]] [--rebuild-cache]**

This is almost all the information I can provide, since I did everything according to the documentation.

I have never worked with WSL and Docker before. It would be great if someone with more experience could help me handle this problem.

Thanks Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Oro team recently [extended the instruction with much more detail](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/setup/dev-environment/docker-and-symfony/windows/). Please start over to make it work. From what I see, the main issue is that you've installed the application in the Windows filesystem, which is way slower than the Linux filesystem. It may lead to many unexpected issues.